# Can SQL Server 2016 Rearrange Order of Multiple Queries in One Transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I experienced a very strange occurrence relating to a multi-query transaction. After SQL Server was updated from 2008 to 2016 (with no warning from our host), we started dropping data after it was posted to the API. The weird thing is, some of the data arrived, and some didn’t.

In order to protect integrity, the queries are all joined in one transaction. The records can be created and then updated at a later time. They are formatted similar to this:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_1 WHERE parentID = 123 AND col2 = 321;
DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE parentID = 123 AND col2 = 321;
-- etc
INSERT INTO table_1 (parentID, col2, etc) VALUES (123, 321, 123456);
INSERT INTO table_2 (parentID, col2, etc) VALUES (123, 321, 654321);
-- etc
```

There could be hundreds of lines being executed. Due to design, the records in question do not have unique IDs, so the most performant way to execute the queries was to first delete the matching records, then re-insert them. Looping through the records and checking for existence is the only other option (as far as I know), and that is expensive with that many records.

Anyway, I was struggling to find a reason for this data loss, which seemed random. I had logs of the sql queries, so I know they were being formatted correctly and they had all the data intact. Finally, the only thing left I could think of was to separate the DELETE queries into a separate transaction and execute first*. That seems to have fixed the problem.

Q. Does anyone know if these queries could be executed out of order in which they were presented? Do you see a better way I could be writing these transactions?

* I don't necessarily like this solution, because the delete queries were the main reason I wanted a transaction in the first place. If an error occurs during the second transaction, then all the older matching records have been deleted, but the newer versions are never saved. Living on the edge...

P.S. One other problem I had, and this is probably due to my ignorance of the platform, when I tried to bracket these queries with `BEGIN TRAN;` and `COMMIT TRAN;`, immediately after this script finished, any following queries in the same thread got hung up for about 20-30 seconds or so. What am I doing wrong? Do I actually need these verbs if all the queries are being executed at once?

Comment: You probably want a clustered index on `(parentID, col2)`, furthermore, you should consider dumping all the changes into a temp table or Table Valued Parameter and doing a single joined `delete` and joined `update`. Yes, if you don't have a transaction then each batch could interfere with the other, transactions create locks to prevent that, which cause the blocking

Comment: Thanks, the clustered index is a good idea (the app is legacy, written in ASP Classic and nearing end-of-life after about 7 years in production). The TVP is something that might be above my pay grade as far as TSQL goes, but I'll certainly look into it.

Comment: TVPs are pretty easy and very useful, but you're not going to be able to coerce classic ASP to understand what they are.

Comment: On second thought with the clustered indexes, it would be awesome to have them, but in the MSN documentation, there are several very serious caveats to creating them on tables with large amounts of data already in them. This line in their documentation sums it up: _The preferred way to build indexes on large tables is to start with the clustered index and then build any nonclustered indexes._

Comment: That's because the clustered key is part of every non-clustered index, so non clustered indexes must also be rebuilt; it's a one-time operation though so plan for it out-of-hours or low use times, if you are using Enterprise Edition you can rebuild online (although the name is a bit misleading). It's also a quick (relatively) way of defragmenting your indexes and updating statistics.

Comment: I would still try to get the data into a temp table and do a joined delete/insert, it's likely a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

We could use a bit more information, such as if there is unique constraint on your table and ignore duplicate insert.
if the data is missing, it could be due to insert failed and this will register an entry in the Profiler event "User Error Message" under "Errors and Warnings" event class. Create a trace to filter this login only and check each statement and if there is any user errors raised in the trace.
If you have a other processes running (other applications or threads), it is possible that after you inserted the records other deleted that row without your knowledge. In this case, you might want to set up a delete trigger to log all update and delete actions on the table and see what is the user performing these actions. In short, if you think you have lost data, it is either the command was not executed , executed with error, or deleted buy other processes after execution.

Comment: There are no constraints on this database. The database is hosted on a shared server and I don't have access to Enterprise Manager. I've thoroughly error-trapped the executed queries and no errors have been thrown. I kept a log of the queries and manually ran them myself - I immediately checked the data and found some missing (no other account or process could have possibly deleted them). The last option I am left with is to believe that SS2016 parsed the queries out of their original order somehow, and the fix works to confirm that theory.